# works when adding Breakpoint ! c# excel error : Unable To Get The Find Property Of The Range Class

Tags: c#, excel, user-defined-functions

I am currently working on application that allows me to read from an excel file after having written in (write a function in cell A1 that generates me a table from cell A2, and then delete the first line), the problem is that every time I read the file ; the title of the first column contain this error :

```
N\A: Impossible de lire la propriété Select de la classe Range. !!!

N \ A: Unable To Get The Find Property Of The Range Class !!!
```

here is the code :

```
var theWorksheet9 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)theWorkbook.Worksheets.Item[10];
            theWorksheet9.Name = "MyFunctionName"; // rename the worksheet
            theWorksheet9.Activate();
            theWorksheet9.Range["A1"].Formula = MyFunction; //set the function
            theWorksheet9.Range["A1"].Calculate();  //execute the function
            theWorksheet9.Calculate();
            //Console.WriteLine(theWorksheet9.Range["A2"].Value2);
            theWorksheet9.Range["A1"].EntireRow.Delete(XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp); // to delete the first row where the function was writed and executed
                //Console.WriteLine(theWorksheet9.Range["A1"].Value2);
```

when i try to show the Header of the first column :

```
Console.WriteLine(theWorksheet9.Range["A2"].Value);
```

it throw me this exception :

```
{"The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Console.WriteLine(string)' and 'System.Console.WriteLine(char[])'"}
```

Comment: Manually check if the cell has any formula errors?

Comment: thank you but there no problem with the formula ... the proof is that it returns a result

Comment: That exception is a C# error, not an Excel error.  Change your writeline code to:  `string str = theWorksheet3.Range["A2"].Value.ToString();`  then  `Console.WriteLine(str);`

Comment: now it throw this exception :      
{"Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference"}

Comment: You will need to post a lot more of your code before anyone can help with this.

Comment: i have a remark : when i debug the solution I get no exception !! is that normal ?